# Handle click button with Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm new with Python and Flask, I have a problem while rendering my page. The function is executed every time I refresh the page but I want the function executed when I click on the SUBMIT button.

Here is my `main.py`:

```
@app.route('/gp_bagging_one_app', methods=['POST','GET'])

def gp_bagging_one_app():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        apk_to_bag = request.form['input']
        if (os.path.isfile("./Downloads/" + apk_to_bag)):
            print("HELLO")
            gp_bag.create_json_for_apk(apk_to_bag[:-4])

        else:
            print("Apk not found in ./Downloads")


    return render_template("GooglePlayStore/gp_bagging_one_app.html")
```

Here is my view :

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h4> Bagging one app. </h4>
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h6>Select an APK to bag:</h6> <input type="file" name="input"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class=" form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light text-primary" >Bag the APK</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I think it's because of my POST method and way to handle the clickevent but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you